# Salesforce - Setting field to Read Only

Tags: security, permissions, salesforce

I am having a dilemma changing a field from Read only. I have a custom field which is a fomula(Checkbox). Field level security is set to visible for all profiles and the Read only checkboxes are also checked for every profile. I am unable to de-select the Read only checkboxes. I tried changing the field from Read only in the layout but I can't seem to be able to uncheck that as well. What can I do about this? The field is set to Read only on my profile and I can't seem to be able to uncheck the Read only when I edit the profile.

Do I need an admin to change this setting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formula fields are always calculated, and therefore always read-only, perhaps you want the field to have a default value formula rather than a calculated value?

Comment: Ah thanks. So in other words, the checkbox will never be in a state where a user can check it if it is a formula field. Is that right?